# Alter a table by attaching another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Really a rookie about T-SQL and the question is simple enough. I have two table with same scheme. I want to attach one into the other one. The only thing I know is 'union', e.g.

```
select * from table1 
union 
select * from table2
```

But, this would generate a new table and double the storage space. I want to know, is there a way to directly change one table by attaching another one? Some thing like

```
insert into table1 values()
```

Really need help! Thx.

Comment: you can create a view instead

Answer (score 2):

A union does not "create storage" because it combines the queries at runtime. The only storage that might be required by a union is temporary space for doing sorting, grouping and things like that.

To insert data from a select into another table you can use the following:

```
insert into table1 (col1, col2, col3)
select col1, col2, col3
from table2
```

But that **will** double the storage because the data of table2 will be stored in table2 *and* table1 until you delete/drop table2 (the source)

Comment: Great! One of my tables is temporary and would be dropped. Therefore, the storage is ok. In the question where I mentioned storage, I actually want to say that using 'union', I think I need to generate another table to store the result of the 'union' query and that would be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using simple `insert into`, if you are not worried about the duplicates records need to be update or keep as it is.

Note : Both tables should have same structure and data type length.

look at this sample code step by step.
This example insert data from emp_backup table into emp table.

```
CREATE table emp
(
empid int,
fname varchar(20),
lname varchar(20)
);

INSERT INTO emp VALUES(1,'vish','dalvi');
INSERT INTO emp VALUES(2,'rohit','kale');
INSERT INTO emp VALUES(3,'vishal','gr');

SELECT * FROM emp;

CREATE table emp_backup
(
empid int,
fname varchar(20),
lname varchar(20)
);

INSERT INTO emp_backup VALUES(6,'mark','novak');
INSERT INTO emp_backup VALUES(7,'gar','pandey');


INSERT into emp
SELECT * FROM emp_backup;

SELECT * FROM emp;
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your goal, what are you attempting to do? As pointed out on first comment, you can create a VIEW using those tables and then launch SELECT's using that view to obtain results merged from both tables. But phisically the original tables will remain independent from one each other. To create a view see the [CREATE VIEW definition and syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx) but basically you can run the following command:

```
CREATE VIEW table1_table2
AS
SELECT *
  FROM Table1
 UNION ALL
SELECT *
  FROM Table2
```

Then just do `SELECT * FROM table1_table2` to get all rows from both tables

Another option, maybe what are you looking for, is to get the data from one table, insert into the other and then delete the first one.

```
INSERT INTO Table1
SELECT * FROM Table2

TRUNCATE Table2
DROP Table2

SELECT * FROM Table1
```